# Trying to use AsyncTask do download some image files

Tags: android, casting, arraylist, android-asynctask, parameters

I have list of files stored inside arraylist that I need to download in background thread. My initial thought is that AsyncTask should be up for that task. But, I have a problem, I don't know how to supply my list to doInBackground method.

My arraylist is defined as

```
private ArrayList<String> FilesToDownload = new ArrayList<String>();
```

My DownloadFiles subclass (the way it is written now) should be called with:
new DownloadFiles().execute(url1, url2, url3, etc.);

This is not suitable for me since I never know how many urls I will have. It is pretty much changing from case to case. So, I would like somehow to pass my arraylist to doInBackground method.

I tried to convert to array with toArray():

```
new DownloadFiles().execute(FilesToDownload.toArray());
```

But, eclipse tells me that execute is not applicable for argument Object[].
Suggestion was to cast to URL[], but when I tried that I got illegal casting error and app crashed.

It seems that doInBackground has to be implemented with parameters in varargs type (URL... urls).

Any ideas how to solve my problem? Thanks.

```
class DownloadFiles extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;        
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             Log.d("Evento", "&&&& downloading: " + FilesToDownload.get(i).toString());
//             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
//             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         }
         return totalSize;
     }
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }
     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
       //showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AsyncTask` is declared with a param type of URL, but you're trying to pass `String` (or `ArrayList`) objects. Either prepare an `Array` of URL objects in the calling program or modify `DownloadFiles` to accept `String` instead of URL parameters and convert each `String` to a URL in the `execute()` method.

Better yet, since you are accessing `FilesToDownload` from within `execute()`, you don't need to pass anything to `execute()` and you could declare the first generic parameter of `DownloadFiles` as `Void`.