# Android - Asynchronous task to load images

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to write an `AsyncTask` which takes an `ImageView` and **path to the image** as input and loads the image in a background thread. I wanted to know how I can pass both the `ImageView` and the path to the `AsyncTask`? The `Params` argument in the `doInBackground` can hold an `array` of data belonging to same class, but this is a different scenario as one of them is a `View` and another one is the path to a file (`String`).

One option I have, is to have the `AsyncTask` as an inner class and declare the `ImageView` as a class variable which can be accessed inside `AsyncTask`. I don't want to do this, because the same task is used by multiple classes and it doesn't conform to the DRY policy.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the ImageView's setTag method, and give it the path of your image.
your asynctask or background thread can then getTag your imageView and do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

The same type of question asked in SO [Android : Loading an image from the Web with Asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090650/android-loading-an-image-from-the-web-with-asynctask) and also look at [Trying to use AsyncTask do download some image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054364/trying-to-use-asynctask-do-download-some-image-files) try it and if you found problem let me know it.

Answer (score 1):

You can the declare the params of the task as a Pair of ImageView and a String.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask< Pair<ImageView, String> >, Integer, Long> {

}
```