# Is json image this hard to be displayed

Tags: android, image, json

I need help displaying this image which I'm pulling from a JSON server.

JSON Value returned:

```
          "photoThumbnailUrl": "http://media.xxx.co.uk/75k/74944/18863829
          /74944_OSI1000044_IMG_00_0000_max_200x138.jpg"
```

I just need to display this image in my application.How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happen..

```
URL newurl;
try
{
newurl = new URL("http://media.xxx.co.uk/75k/74944/18863829/74944_OSI1000044_IMG_00_0000_max_200x138.jpg");
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
}
catch (IOException e)
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks mate,it is partialy worked.I can parse the images as a json string.but what I need is to display the images when the response is recieved.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON download the image to a local file using some asynctask
here´s a sample 
[Trying to use AsyncTask do download some image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054364/trying-to-use-asynctask-do-download-some-image-files)
then use a ImageView to reflect it:
here's a link
[Show Image View from file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android)

---

hope it helps

Comment: Ok,I have been trying to solve this prob for sometime andI have managed to parse the image but I can't displayed as image.I will try these links thanks.

Comment: @user1176963 Just as a warning - there's no such file in the server. 404.